# SQl query optimization in workbench

Tags: mysql

Running a query in SQL takes a lot of time.

There are 240000000 total rows and 7700000 unique rows.

Try to calculate the average daily step count of the user between 3000 and 4000.

```
select count(distinct user_id) from (SELECT user_id,ROUND(AVG(IF(steps>'0',steps,NULL)),0) AS `Average Steps`
 FROM `step_activity`.`step_activities`  where user_id between '1100001' and '9999999' group by user_id 
 having  `Average Steps` between '3000' and '4000') as custlt3k;
```

#### just want to know the total number of users.###

Comment: If you want help optimizing a query, please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables used and `explain select ...rest of your query `

Comment: I think "lac" means 100000, but I don't know what "cr" means

Comment: 24 crore rows in data

Comment: What do you mean by unique rows?  That many different user_id?

Comment: yes, 
 we have a table of user details like user id, steps ( user no of steps) daily records updated in the table.
we want to calculate to no of unique user count which avg steps between 3k to 4k

Comment: it is impossible to help if you don\`t show table structures, l need to know about indexes

Comment: and please provide version of mysql

Comment: Why are you testing against strings eg steps>'0' ?

Comment: Sql workbench 8.0

Comment: @P.Salmon - He wants to consider only the exercise times, not count when he is sleeping.  I think he will eventually realize that "average" is not a good metric because of the occasional "1" or "5" in the table.  Walking to the bathroom one extra time will lower the average for a day.

Comment: @DheerajKumar - Your data covers all activity since you started recording it?  I would expect there to be a limit of one month (or something).  If you add that limitation, then I would suggest having daily summary table rows instead of the huge raw data table

Comment: please help us help you.  If you want help optimizing a query, please edit your question to show (as text, not images) output of `show create table yourtablename` for all tables used and `explain select ...rest of your query`

Answer (score 0):

The `GROUP BY` in the derived table (inner query) makes the `user_id` distinct.  Hence, the `DISTINCT` is not needed.  CHange to simply `COUNT(*)`.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so we can see if you have an index starting with `user_id`, which might be beneficial.  Also how many rows in `step_activities` and how many rows with `user_id between '1100001' AND '9999999'`.  Comparing those will determine whether the index will even be used.

The task requires all the rows, at least the rows with that range of users, to be read, and "grouped".

This index *may* help:  `INDEX(user_id, steps)` because that would be a "covering" index.

Another thing to consider -- don't store any rows with `steps = 0`.  After all, they are being thrown out in this query.  (Maybe there are other columns in the row that you need to keep?)